# Input value is deleted on applying filters to suggestion items for Sap.m.Input

Tags: sapui5

I am working on Sap.m.Input suggestion items. Suggestions for the input is working fine but when i choose an item from the suggestions list and then remove the value and enter a new value, it is deleting the freshly entered value automatically without showing any suggestions. I debugged my code and the value is deleted at line oBinding.filters(). My code is as below,

```
<Input id="input" placeholder="{i18n>input}" editable="true" startSuggestion="2"
                showSuggestion="true" suggest="handleSuggest"  
                 suggestionItemSelected="onSelectedItem" 
                 suggestionItems="{path:'abc>/abSet',templateShareable:true, parameters:{select: 'ab,bc'}}">
                    <suggestionItems growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true">
                                <core:Item key="{abc>ab}" text="{abc>ab} {abc>bc}"/>
                    </suggestionItems>
                </Input>
```

controller

```
handleSuggest: function (oEvent) {
            var sTerm = oEvent.getParameter("suggestValue"),
                oSource = oEvent.getSource(),
                oBinding,
                aFilters = [];
            oSource.setBusy(false);
            if (sTerm) {
                aFilters.push(new Filter("bc", FilterOperator.Contains, sTerm));
                aFilters.push(new Filter("cd", FilterOperator.EQ, ""));
                aFilters.push(new Filter("de",FilterOperator.EQ, ""));
            }

            oBinding = oSource.getBinding("suggestionItems");
            var Filters = [];   
            Filters.push(new Filter({
                filters: aFilters,
                and: true
            }));

            oBinding.getModel().setSizeLimit(500);
            oBinding.filter(Filters);


        },

        //Once the suggestion BP is choosen retreiving the key
        onSelectedItem: function (oEvent) {
            var sItems = oEvent.getParameter("selectedItem");
            if (sItems !== null)
                filterValue = sItems.getKey();

        },
```

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: What is the UI5 version of your app?

Comment: 1.52...BTW I have the same code running with no such issues in the app with version 1.41

Comment: Recently I'm having some issues with suggestionItems too... I'm still figuring out if it is a matter of code or I am missing something

Comment: Please post here if you find something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the solution was removing the property `key` from the `<core:Item />` elements in the `suggestionItems` aggregation.
After version 1.44 something changed and the property `key` somewhat causes some strange behaviors but I still can't figure it out why.

Comment: Solved but not explained :)

Comment: I had the same problem because I attached a dataReceived event to binding of input field. In the event listener function, I was  refreshing model. Removing dataReceived event (model refresh) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

"After version 1.44 something changed and the property key somewhat causes some strange behaviors but I still can't figure it out why."

**To avoid strange behavior please add valueLiveUpdate="true"**

Your code shoud look like this

```
<Input 
  id="input" 
  placeholder="{i18n>input}" 
  editable="true" 
  startSuggestion="2"
  showSuggestion="true" 
  suggest="handleSuggest"  
  suggestionItemSelected="onSelectedItem"
  valueLiveUpdate="true"
  suggestionItems="{
    path: 'abc>/abSet',
    templateShareable: true, 
    parameters:{select: 'ab,bc'}
  }">
  <suggestionItems 
    growing="true" 
    growingScrollToLoad="true">
    <core:Item key="{abc>ab}" text="{abc>ab} {abc>bc}"/>
  </suggestionItems>
</Input>
```